Trying to design a circuit to power an MCU that demands high current pulses
I'm trying to model an MCU powered on batteries. The MCU will be sending data over BLE, so it will pull a large amount of current; more than the maximum discharge current of the battery. To solve this problem, I want to keep the MCU in sleep mode most of the time while charging a supercapacitor. Then, wake up the MCU and send BLE for a short period of time with the help of such supercap.
The MCU works at 3.3V and the batteries I have searched are 3V. Hence, I plan to connect 2 batteries in series to a switching regulator that will convert from 6V to 3.3V.
This is a high level schematics of what I have in mind:

I'm trying to model this system in order to calculate the capacitor and simulate it, but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly, so I want to ask if the following strategy makes sense:
I believe I need to achieve the following:

When the MCU is in sleep mode, the batteries are able to power it while also they charge the supercapacitor over time.
When the MCU is awake, I need to make sure that the circuit connected to the regulator's input can provide enough power to satisfy the regulator's output demands long enough.
I need to make sure the current pulled from the battery never exceeds \$20\$mA, or rather \$18\$mA for safety.

Is the reasoning above correct?
If so, these are the calculations I made.
Calculate supercapacitor
When the MCU is awake, it will consume \$100\text{mA @ } 3.3\text{V} = 0.33\text{W}\$. I want this state to last for 10 seconds before enabling the sleep mode, so I need the capacitor to hold \$0.33 * 10 = 3.3 \text{Joules}\$.
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}CV^2
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{2}C6^2 \geq{3.3}
$$
So \$C = 330\text{mF}\$ should be more than enough.
Sleep mode and charging supercapacitor
When the MCU is in sleep mode, it will consume \$10\text{mA @ } 3.3\text{V} = 0.033\text{W}\$. The batteries can provide up to \$20\text{mA @ }6\text{V}\$. Hence, the batteries can provide enough power to the MCU at the same time the charge the supercap.
Model and simulation
I have tried to do this but I have been unable; I'm focusing on the capacitor discharge stage.
I have modeled the battery with a current step of \$18\$mA in parallel with a \$330\$Ohm resistor. This allows me to charge the capacitor up to \$6\$V (what whould happen with real batteries) and to assure the "batteries" branch won't provide more than the defined maxumum of \$18\$mA.
I let the capacitor charge until about \$5.5\$V (about \$5\$ minutes) and then I close a switch that connects a BJT current regulator that pulls about \$55\$mA. As explained above, \$6\cdot55\cdot10^{-3} = 0.33\text{W}\$ which is the power that the actual BLE device would demand.
As per my calculations above, I should be able to provide \$0.33\$W for \$10\$ second or more. However, when I simulate the circuit, the capacitor voltage drops so quick that the whole circuit stops providing \$33\$W almost as soon as the current regulator connects.

Link to circuitlab
In general, I'm unable to find the right way to model and simulate this. Could I get some help, please?
EDIT
I have modified the MCU model \$R3\$ to be \$10\$ Ohms and \$R2\$ (resistor connected to the BJT's base) to \$570\$ Ohms, so that the current regulator pulls about \$100\$ mA constantly.
I did this to make the model to pull the real amount of current the MCU will in production (\$100\$ mA). This way, the capacitor starts dropping voltage but the circuit keeps providing \$0.33\$ W or more until the cap. voltage gets below \$3.3\$.
With the above, the capacitor seems to be able to keep the supply of power for about 7 seconds; better but not even close to what I calculated.
I think this is because the model is not very good: the capacitor is providing more than \$0.33\$ W until it reaches \$3.3\$ V.
I think this wouldn't happen with an switching regulator; at the beginning (when the cap's voltage is about \$5.5\$ V), the switching regulator would demand less than \$100\$ mA as the voltage is higher than needed at the output. Am I right?
How can I model a constant demand of \$0.33\$ W that adapts to the provided voltage?

hm, what's the internal resistance of your battery (in other words: at 18 mA or 20 mA drawn, how much does its voltage sag)? And of your supercapacitor? I'd include these two resistances in a model of simply putting capacitor and battery in parallel and then activating your 55 mA load. Then, in your simulator, get curve for the current flowing out of the battery and the supercap over the first couple milliseconds.

I have realised that I possibly don't need to simulate the above in order to find out the capacitor I need.
My reasoning is:
I know that the required power by the load is \$3.3\cdot100 = 0.33\text{W}\$.
I want to keep that power at the output for \$10\$ seconds, so the total energy required is \$0.33\cdot10=3.3\text{ Joules}\$.
I need to be able to supply that energy at the buck converter's input with a supercapacitor. The battery that will charge such cap. over a certain period of time is \$6\text{ V}\$ so, for simplicity, let's assume the capacitor is alone supplying the energy above, with an initial voltage of \$5.5\text{V}\$. I don't use \$6\text{ V}\$ as charging from \$5.5\$ to \$6\$ takes a lot of time and it's not worth it to leave the MCU that much time without transmitting, while the capacitor charges, just for half volt more.
Let's also assume, for simplicity, that the buck converter requires a min. voltage of \$3.6\text{ V}\$ at the input to produce a \$3.3 \text{ V}\$ at the output. The voltage at the supercap. will start dropping as soon as it starts to supply current, so the energy I calculated above needs to be fully provided before the  supercap falls below \$3.6 \text{ V}\$.
From the capacitor fundamental laws, it's known that:
$$
E_{stored} = \frac{CV^2}{2}
$$
In this case, the formula alone won't work as the capacitor cannot fully discharge; it can only reach \$3.6 \text{ V}\$. Thus:
$$
E_{stored-3.6} = C(\frac{V_{init}^2}{2} - \frac{V_{min}^2}{2})
$$
or
$$
3.3 = C(\frac{5.5^2}{2} - \frac{3.6^2}{2})
$$
Hence
$$
C_{required} = \frac{3.3}{(\frac{5.5^2}{2} - \frac{3.6^2}{2})} = 0.38 \text{ F}
$$
So, the minum capacitance required would be \$0.38\$ Farads.To be safe, I will pick a \$0.4\$ or \$0.5\$ Farads supercapacitor.
Model
To check the calculations are correct, it's enough to simulate a capacitor charged with the voltage above, and then leave it powering a load that constantly pulls \$\approx 100\text{ mA}\$



As you can see, the supercap. is able to provide about \$100\text{ mA}\$ for about \$10\text{ s}\$ without dropping below \$3.6\text{ V}\$.
See in CircuitLab
